# How is spring flux cache item managed

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Consider code example:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.time.Duration;

import static com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of;

@Component
public class Scratch {

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    public Mono<MyClass> getMyClass(Long id) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("{id}", of("id", id))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(MyClass.class)
                .cache(Duration.ofHours(1));
    }
}
```

The specification [tells](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#cache-java.time.Duration-):

> Will retain an unbounded history but apply a per-item expiry timeout

What is item and what is cached?

1. Entire http call is cached. E.g. if I call method chain `.get().uri()` with `id = 1` any subsequent calls will be cached? or
2. Only `Mono<MyClass>` is cached. E.g. any subsequent call to `Mono.map` will use cached value?

In both cases what is considered as item?

Answer (score 5):

The `cache` operator in Reactor is very different from something like a `@Cacheable` annotation on a component method.

For example, the `@Cacheable` annotation will:

- intercept method calls and compute a cache key from the method parameters
- call the method and store the result in an external cache
- provide the cached result whenever something else calls that method with the same params

All Reactor operators are decorators, they return a new instance of a `Flux`/`Mono` - [this is why you need to chain operators](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.chain).

Let's take this example:

```
Scratch scratch = //...
Mono<MyClass> myClass = scratch.getMyClass(12L);
```

This means that every time something subscribes to that particular `Mono` instance (so not `scratch.getMyClass(44L);`, nor any other instance returned by another `scratch.getMyClass(12L);` call), Reactor will return the elements cached when it was consumed the first time.

When Reactor talks about elements, those are the instances of `MyClass` messages; because here, the cache operator has been added after `bodyToMono`. It would be a different story if you were to add that operator somewhere else in the pipeline, i.e. it would cache a different thing.

Now this is not a feature that will implement HTTP client caching for all similar HTTP calls. This feature is useful if several parts of your application need the exact same data and you don't want to waste resources fetching the same thing over and over.

For example, let's say this HTTP call is expensive and you want to consume that `MyClass` instance in several places:

```
Mono<MyClass> myClass = scratch.getMyClass(12L);
Mono<Void> result = saveToDatabase(myClass).then(calculateStats(myClass));
```

Another use case for this, is when you'd like to share a stream of data to several clients:

```
@RestController
public class StreamingController {

    private Flux<StockQuotes> quotes = quoteService.fetch().cache(Duration.ofSeconds(5));

    @GetMapping("/quotes")
    public Flux<StockQuotes> streamQuotes() {
        return this.quotes;
    }
```

In this case, every time a new HTTP client is requesting the server and streaming data from it, the server won't create a new connection to the remote stock service and will replay the quotes of the last 5 seconds (and then proceed with the rest) for all new subscriptions.